# error: Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x10e404918) to 'NSString' (0x10d5fac60). (lldb)

Tags: swift

I'm getting the error likewise:

> Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x10e404918) to 'NSString' (0x10d5fac60). (lldb)

I have used a tableview here and I calling the function to parse and fetch the json values using model class I'm storing the fetched values. Here is the code which gives error It is not proceeding further to parse json file:

```
temp.Nameofngo = obj.object(forKey: "Nameofngo") as! String!
```

Comment: this is not option obj.object(forKey: "Nameofngo") thats why you are getting error, create json object optional then try hope so it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`null` (`NSNull` in Swift) is a valid JSON type which is used as a placeholder for `nil`.

Just use optional downcast and the *nil coalescing operator* to assign a default value in the `null` case.

```
temp.Nameofngo = obj["Nameofngo"] as? String ?? ""
```

If `temp.Nameofngo` – by the way variable names are supposed to start with a lowercase letter – is an optional anyway you can even omit `?? ""`